# Option for auto Masspay in ubercart marketplace

Tags: ubercart

Is there any auto Masspay option in ubercart marketplace module. Now working with manual payment method.

Answer (score 0):

[Automatic mass payment (with paypal only)](https://www.drupal.org/node/921488)

Explanation:
When a user makes an order and pays with PayPal or does ExpressCheckout with PayPal and the system redirects him to "checkout/complete" the added code starts to work and makes masspay for all the orders done before that one. (Newest order not included)

**Another Method :**

- Go to Test Accounts, select "Create Account: Preconfigured", Choose
  account type "Seller", use given data
- Go to API Credentials, copy API Username, Password, and Signature to
  Drupal Enable uc_paypal module
- Setup PayPal Website Payment Pro settings at: "Store Administration

  > > Configuration >> Payment Settings >> Edit >> Payment Gateways" or directly via /admin/store/settings/payment/edit/gateways
- Enable this payment gateway for use API server: Sandbox
- Now enter your API credentials
- If IPN is setup you may now make payments at "Store administration >>
  reports >> Seller reports"